# Does it make a difference to pass a pointer to a pointer as an argument or simply pass the first pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm sorry if this sounds vague or idiotic, but consider the following:

if I have a main function like so:

```
int main(void)
{
   int red_wins = 0;
  game_loop(&red_wins); 
  // code 
  printf("red has %d wins\n", red_wins); 
}
```

then have a a game_loop function which calls another function that uses red_wins:

```
void game_loop(int *red_wins)
{
  // code 
  particle_move(red_wins);
}
```

and then another function called particle_move which uses this red_wins variable:

```
void particle_move(int *red_wins) 
{
  // code 
  if (such and such)
  {
    *red_wins+= 10; 
  } 
}
```

where `red_wins` is only modified in the `particle_move` function and `particle_move` is only called from the `game_loop` function, would it be better to do it as shown above or by passing a pointer to a pointer in the `particle_move` function? Or, but I've been told it's bad practice, by using a global variable `red_wins`? Or is there another, better, way that I've overlooked?

Comment: It should be `particle_move(red_wins);`. Try compiling it, the compiler will point out the type mismatches.

Comment: You generally only need a pointer to a pointer if you're intending on manipulating the pointer itself.

Comment: To your question in the title: These are very different. Assuming you provide valid prototypes for your functions, your compiler should warn you about such a mismatch. Besides that, your question does not match your title. That should be avoided as it is hard to decide which question to answer.

Comment: @Gerhardh of course, but what if I change the prototypes as well?

Comment: If you change the prototype as well (and the signature of your function definition) then the called function takes a different type of argument.

Comment: @EugeneSh. oops you're right, I typed my examples falsely. I do in fact call it like `particle_move(red_wins)`

Comment: If you correct it, then your code is just fine (up to typos, such as lack of `;`) .

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: @tadman I tried to but it wouldn't let me hit tab for some reason :(

Comment: Should be able to indent with spaces, but it's usually easier to get it in order in an editor before copy-pasting. No big deal, but it really helps us see your intent more clearly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know it works but I'm asking, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: There is no conceptual issue with it. It is one way to do the thing, which is totally fine and won't be something I would flag if I saw it in a code review.

Comment: There's a TamperMonkey script called `stackexchange-tab-editing` that allows you to use the TAB key in the SO editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to pass a pointer to pointer in the following situations:

- Where the called function is updating the *pointer* value, not the thing being pointed to:

  ```
  void update( T **p )
  {
    *p = new_TStar_value();
  }

  int main( void )
  {
    T *var;
    update( &var ); // updates var
  }
  ```

  Where the pointer is pointing to the first in a sequence of pointers:

  ```
  void foo( int **p )
  {
    // do something interesting
  }

  int main( void )
  {
    int **p = malloc( sizeof *p * ROWS );
    if ( p )
    {
      for ( size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
        p[i] = malloc( sizeof *p[i] * COLS )
    }
    foo( p );
    return 0;
  }
  ```

In your case, `particle_move` is updating the same thing that `game_loop` is updating, so you don't need to add another layer of indirection.  You're doing it right, here.